# .htaccess rewrite only selected url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This may have been asked somewhere but i was unable to find solution for me.

I want to rewrite only selected url, like

```
www.example.com/page_1 to www.example.com/page.php?page=page_1
www.example.com/page_2 to www.example.com/page.php?page=page_2
www.example.com/page_3 to www.example.com/page.php?page=page_3
www.example.com/page_3_1 to www.example.com/page.php?page=page_3_1
```

and for other url's like www.example.com/page_4 , www.example.com/page_5, etc it must not do anything.

i want a pattern like solution, so that i can add other url's to it easily.

Comment: Are those just _simplified examples_ (`page_1,page_2,page_3`) or are those the _actual_ URLs you intend to redirect? (it makes a difference for how the regex could be constructed)

Comment: these are simplified examples, since i have only few number of url's to which i want internal rewrite to page page.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(page_1|page_2|page_3|page_3_1)/?$ /page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```